# Translating Java code to ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, while-loop, arm

I want to translate a java code that calculates the sum from 1 to n to arm assembly, and I am wondering if I am translating it correctly?

Here is the code I java code i am translating:

```
 int sum = 0 ;
 int num = 10; 
 int count = 1 ;
 while ( count <= num )
 {
  sum += count ; 
  count++ ;
 }
 System.out.println(sum);
```

And here is my arm assembly code so far:

```
    MOV r1, #0      ;store sum
    MOV r2, #10     ;number to count to
    MOV r3, #1      ;starting count

start_while:            ;start while loop
    CMP r3, r2      ;while count is less than number
    ADD r1, r1, r3  ;add count to sum
    ADD r3, r3, #1  ;increment count
    BNE start_while     ;end while loop
    ;print sum???
```

Am I translating the while loop correctly and how do I print the sum? Sorry I am fairly new to arm assembly so I don't know if I'm doing it right.

Comment: Run it under a debugger to see if the final value is what you expect.  Debuggers can substitute for littering your code with prints (which is really inconvenient in asm).

Comment: Ok I see that r1 is equal to 55 which is what I expect, so how do I print it in  print the value of r1 to standard output?

Comment: Depending on what OS you're on, you can just call printf.  Look up the ARM calling convention to find out where to put the args.

Answer (score 0):

while () is usually translate like this:

```
_start:
if (!condition) jump to _end
    ; do stuff inside the while loop
    jump to _start
_end:
```

so your loop would look like this:

```
    MOV r1, #0      ;store sum
    MOV r2, #10     ;number to count to
    MOV r3, #1      ;starting count

start_while:        ; start while loop
    CMP r3, r2      ; jump below while block if while condition is
    BGT end_while  ; not true anymore ( "<= 10" gets ">10")
    ADD r1, r1, r3  ;add count to sum
    ADD r3, r3, #1  ;increment count
    B start_while       ;go on with loop (no condition here)
end_while:
    ;print sum???
```